# Unable to connect to .MDB database with ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access, webforms, oledb

I'm trying to create a simple user registration system using ASP.NET C# and an MS Access .mdb database. The problem is, whenever I attempt to register, the code fails at the `OleDbCommand` in the "try" and gets "caught" instead. I have used breakpoints in MS Visual Studio 2012 and all keys are present as far as I can tell. My code follows:

Here is my class where the registration method is located:

```
 public static class DbUtil
    {

    private static OleDbConnection openConnection()
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

        try
        {
            string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|MainDatabase.mdb";
            con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return con;
    }

    private static void closeConnection(OleDbConnection con)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public static bool registerUser(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection con = openConnection())
            {
                string sqlString = @"INSERT INTO Users (Email, Password) VALUES (?, ?)";
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", email);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    closeConnection(con);
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where the method is called:

```
public void btnRegisterSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strEmail = txtRegisterEmail.Text;
        string strPassword = txtRegisterPassword.Text;

        bool regSuccess = DbUtil.registerUser(strEmail, strPassword);
        if (regSuccess == false)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?reg=fail");
        }
        else
        {
            if (regSuccess == true)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?reg=success");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?reg=error");
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm currently using the praised parameter method, for the first time. I did use a simple concatenation method in the SQL string, but this yielded the same problem.

Also, there are no errors printed or exceptions thrown.

Any help at all would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Exception:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()   at DbUtil.registerUser(String email, String password) in c:\Users\******\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\********************\App_Code\DbUtil.cs:line 51
```

Comment: You're not handling the exception in your registerUser method; it's probably being thrown in that scope, so you probably want to do the same thing for that catch that you did in your other methods.

Comment: By the way, writing a catch handler like you did in registerUser is probably never a good idea. All you've done is detect that something failed, but ignore all the information you could use to diagnose the problem. There's a lot going on in that scope which could fail for any number of reasons. Even if you plan to beef it up later, too easy for something like that to fall through the cracks and leave you with mysterious problems as you continue your project.

Comment: Thanks for your second comment, I'll make sure to correctly handle exceptions. Ill paste the exception in the question. It seems to be the OleDbCommand as I initially though, I just don't see the problem. Also, the asterisks' are just to sensor names.

Comment: ODBC uses question marks as parameter markers, but I don't think it will work for OleDb. Try named parameters instead, so (?, ?) becomes (@Email, @Password) and you have to prefix the names in the AddWithValue calls so AddWithValue("Email", email) becomes AddWithValue("@Email", email) etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried but the same exception was thrown, and still no data added :(

Comment: Wondering if reserved words could be the problem i.e. "password". I think you can enclose the column name in square brackets to force its interpretation as a column name; otherwise, you might want/need to choose a different name for the column.

Comment: I already checked those, I'm not using any reserved words :/

Comment: Do you have Write access to the folder that the Access database is located in?

Comment: Yes I do, thanks for the comment though. According to the exception, it seems to be a problem with the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this fixed. I rewrote the `registerUser()` method, and removed the `using` blocks and it now works great. Here's the code with the removed parts commented:

```
public static bool registerUser(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            //using (OleDbConnection con = openConnection())
            //{
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|MainDatabase.mdb");
                string sqlString = "INSERT INTO [Users] ([Email], [Password]) VALUES (@Email, @Password)";
                //using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, con))
                //{
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, con);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
                    con.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                    return true;
                //}
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the comments :)

Comment: When you can, you should probably click on the check mark next to this answer so it shows as answered.

Comment: I will, it said I have to wait two days though :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not using any reserved words

`password` is indeed a reserved word in Access SQL. The following code fails with

> OleDbException was unhandled: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace oledbTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\__tmp\testData.accdb;"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                        @"INSERT INTO Users (Email, Password) VALUES (?, ?)",
                        conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "gord@example.com");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "myPassword");
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the code to...

```
...
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(
        @"INSERT INTO Users (Email, [Password]) VALUES (?, ?)",
        conn))
{
...
```

...then it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working though. I already tried putting square brackets around the column names and that didn't fix it.